# WPF: Setting the ViewModel from XAML, why the second solution doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

This version works

```
<UserControl x:Class="FrequentKeywordsFinder"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:SeoZoomReader.ViewModels">
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel />
  </UserControl.DataContext>
```

This version doesn't Work

```
<UserControl x:Class="FrequentKeywordsFinder"             
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:SeoZoomReader.ViewModels"
             DataContext="viewModels:FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel">
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose the type in attributes in curly braces:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FrequentKeywordsFinder"             
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:SeoZoomReader.ViewModels"
         DataContext="{viewModels:FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel}">
```

And (though I don't know the difference to your first version), if you want to use the type this way, it needs to derive from `MarkupExtension` and override its `ProvideValue` method:

```
public class FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel : MarkupExtension
{
    //...

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both versions work. But they are doing different things.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
     <viewModels:FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

is an equivalent of

```
public FrequentKeywordsFinder()
{
     this.DataContext = new FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel();
}
```

and `DataContext="viewModels:FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel"` is an equivalent of

```
public FrequentKeywordsFinder()
{
     this.DataContext = "viewModels:FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel";
}
```

And the catch is that you shouldn't use any of them, because UserControls are supposed to receive DataContext of the view (Window) they are used in. DataContext is user's (client's) data. Users might disagree with usage of FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel, or at the very least has thier own instance of FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel